# How can I setup the DocuSign Connect feature while I am developing locally on my laptop

Tags: docusignapi

I want to connect docusign locally to my application. How it can be done? How can I setup the DocuSign Connect feature while I am developing locally on my laptop? Please guide me with detailed steps.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to have your network forward an externally accessible url to your localbox.

Since Connect is a service hosted at DocuSign and requires a valid endpoint to send data to, and if `RequireAcknowledgement` is enabled, you'll have to send data back to the service as well.